# How to remove array symbol at the start of terminal Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, ps1

I'm new to Mac and I changed the PS1 environment variable to make it look like Ubuntu. I don't know if I screwed something up or if this is a natural Mac thing, but whenever I do a command, there's an array symbol that goes at the front of the now-executed line. Is there any way of removing this?

```
[user@MBP:~$ ls
user@MBP:~$
```

Here's my PS1:

```
'${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com), the [Unix & Linux stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com), and [Superuser](https://superuser.com) would all be better places to ask about this. Also, are you using bash or zsh as your shell? And I'm fairly sure `debian_chroot` isn't going to be useful on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with *your* changed PS1 environment variable. This is a terminal setting on your mac. To remove these **square brackets** (`[`) at the start of each line in your terminal, you have to do the following setting:

Open Terminal, click <kbd>View</kbd> at the menu list and then <kbd>Hide Marks</kbd>

For more information look at this question on [apple-stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209635/what-functionality-do-marks-offer-in-the-el-capitan-terminal).